# onActivityResult()is not called after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I have an issue.

If I calls `startActivityForResult()` from fragment A, method `onActivityResult()` is called. But if i calls it from fragment B (which have `onActivityResult()` method) using the same code, method `onActivityResult()` also is called, but not always.

If I will turn my device with opened activity, `onActivityResult()` is not called. But within fragment A it is called even in this case.

Have you any idea about this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should save a state when paused and then after rotation start the activity for result again. Or you can handle screen rotation by yourself in the main activity registering for config changes in the manifest.